# Twisted(asynch server) vs Django(or any other framework)

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, twisted, real-time

I need help understanding what the advantage of using an asynch framework is. Suppose I want to develop a simple chat web app. Why cant I write python code in the Django framework that does long polling where I dont send a response back the server until someone enters a new msg. What does Twisted provide that gives it an advantage for real-time apps like the chat app?

Sorry I am obviously little confused about the need for an asynchronous framework.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Asynchronous servers support much larger numbers of simultaneous client connections. More conventional servers come up against thread and process limits when servicing large number of concurrent clients, particularly those with long-lived connections. Async servers can also provide better performance as they avoid the overheads of e.g. thread context switching.

As well as the `Twisted` framework, there are also asynchronous server building blocks in Python's standard library: previously `asyncore` and `asynchat`, but now also `asyncio`.

Answer (score 19):

First off Django is a framework for writing web apps so it provides ORM, html templating, it requires running an http server etc.  Twisted helps to write much lower level code than that.  You could use twisted to write the http server Django runs on.  If you use Django you are limited to http model, with twisted it could be communicating in any protocol you like  including push protocols.  So for your chat example you get a server that scales better since it can push comments to people who have logged in VS with django every client having to poll repeatedly.

edited to reflect comments by: sos-skyl

Comment: not really true; Django does synchronous IO calls which is why it's either OR.

Comment: It isn't the focus on asynchronous so much as it is what the stack looks like.  With Django it is a webserver, a WSGI implementation, Django, my code. With Twisted it is Twisted, my code.  Using twisted one could write a webserver, a XMPP server, an IRC server. With Django a lot of that flexibility is gone you are bound to HTTP as your protocol.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest advantage for me is that Twisted gives me an application that has state, and can communicate with many different clients using many protocols.

For me, my Twisted server communicates with a number of sensors installed in houses and businesses that monitor power usage. It stores the data and keeps recent data and state in handy-dandy python classes in memory. Requests via xmlrpc from django get this state and can present recent data to the user. My Gridspy stuff is still in development so the actual site at your.gridspy.co.nz is a bit pre-alpha.

The best part is that you need surprisingly little code to make an effective server. An amazing amount of the work is done for you.

Answer (score 3):

In twisted you can implement protocols of your own.  Django certainly can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WHIFF](http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/docs/W.intro) instead of either :).  Check out
http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/gfChat/nucularChatRoom
which uses a javascript polling loop with json to check
for server updates.  You could probably do something similar
in Django, but I don't know how because I gave up on Django.

btw: I'm hoping to move this demo onto the google app engine
as a more complete service when
my life calms down a bit.

Comment: If you use twisted, you can use twisted.orbited to push updates from the server to javascript clients running in the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to look at some source for integrating Twisted and Django, have a look at [Yardbird](http://zork.net/motd/nick/django/introducing-yardbird.html).