# Tornado web server/framework

Tags: django, apache, tornado

I am a bit confused, [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) is web server like a apache http server, or a framework like django,   or both?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tornado is a server and framework if you want to make some apps with it.

I use Tornado to serve my django apps, with help of *nginx* (load balancer to run more than 1 Tornado instance) and supervisor to make those tornados live if my apps fail.

I use [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com) and the performance of my apps got better with Tornado instead of serving them with apache.

Answer (score 2):

Tornado is both a non-blocking web server and a lightweight web framework.

It can act as web server to other web frameworks such as Django through the use of tornado.wsgi, but also possesses a core web framework with functionality such as templating (tornado.template), SQL database integration (tornado.database), and OpenID authorization (tornado.auth).  Many developers use it for its superior performance as a non-blocking web server in conjunction with other wsgi capable frameworks, but it's much more than just a web server.

[Tornado Documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Tornado is asynchronous (+ single threaded) and event-driven. Apache http and django are not.

The "Django vs Tornado" [is](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2243213) [an](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/4c78c84ffcc03c1a) [ongoing](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-developers@googlegroups.com/msg22912.html) [flame](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/sep/15/using-django-inside-tornado-web-server/) [war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412169/twistedasynch-server-vs-djangoor-any-other-framework)

IMHO I would start with Tornado (or [Deft](http://incubator.apache.org/deft/) if you like the JVM).

Disclaimer: I'm a Deft committer.

Comment: Looks like the Deft link is dead.